# slideToggle not animating (need help related to the code i have)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/32oumq5k/

The problem: i have been sitting here for 2 hours, searching, editing and trying new things, please excuse me if the code isnt the best (im new to javascript) and well... the CSS is messy also .-. which is probably why i cant find a solution.

but basically, slideToggle wont animate (well it does, but not for what i want it to), inside the fiddle you will find alot of CSS (most of it can be ignored) but what im trying to create is a navigation menu that gracefully slides up an down... using slideToggle, a normal ul with no styling works just fine, but for some reason my style messes everything up  :(

i have tried many different positions, heights, widths, displays, different divs, renaming things, padding, even removed all the z-indexes because i thought that could be the problem. one thing i did notice when doing all of this is that if the background color for the ul is set (to visualise the animation... it animates from 310px to like 300px and then just dissapears which leads me to belive its not actually sliding any child elements it has inside which is confusing

if anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated :/ maybe some fresh eyes could help me solve this issue. Also this is NOT a duplicate, i have been to literally 50 other slideToggle stackoverflow questions NONE helped, even when combining two or more answers... so i think the best thing to do would be to get an answer in relation to my exact problem.

thanks in advance. if i missed anything please let me know.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nav").hide();
  $(function() {
    var pull = $('#menu');
    menu = $('#nav');
    menuHeight = menu.height();

    $("#menu").click(function() {
      menu.slideToggle(200);
    });

    $("#pull").click(function() {
      $(".test").slideToggle(700);
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
      var w = $(window).width();
      if (w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
        menu.removeAttr('style');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* START RESET */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-weight: inherit;
 font-style: inherit;
 font-size: 100%;
 font-family: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
 outline: 0;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
 color: black;
 background: white;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
 text-align: left;
 font-weight: normal;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: "" "";
}

/* END RESET */

html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

#navBar {
 transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #349BD4;
 position: fixed;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

#navBar #navContent {
 transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 1200px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: #FFF;
}

#navBar #navContent ul {
 transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 background-color: #FFF;
 height: 100%;
 width: 800px;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#navBar #navContent ul li {
 transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
 display: block;
 width: auto;
}

#navBar #navContent ul li a {
 width: 90px;
 height: 20px;
 padding: 15px;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #2C363F;
 transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

#navBar #navContent ul li a:hover {
 background-color: #349BD4;
 color: #FFF;
 transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

#navBar #navContent ul li a.active {
 transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 background-color: #349BD4;
 color: #FFF;
}

#navBar #navContent #server {
 float: right;
 display: block;
 height: 20px;
 width: auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 color: #2C363F;
 border-radius: 15px;
 font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
 transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

#navBar #navContent #server:hover {
 background-color: #349BD4;
 color: #FFF;
 transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#navBar #navContent #menu {
 transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 display: none;
 width: 40px;
 height: 30px;
 margin: 5px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 padding-top: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 float: right;
 border: 2px solid #AEC1D3;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #787878;
}

#header {
 
}

#main {
 width: 100%;
 height: 3000px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 top: 54px;
}
.test {
 margin-top: 100px;
}

#pull {
 margin-top: 90px;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 761px) and (max-width: 1240px) {
 
#navBar {
 width: 100%;
}

#navBar #navContent {
 width: 100%;
}
 
#navBar #navContent #server {
 opacity: 0;
 content: none;
 color: #FFF;
}

#navBar #navContent #server:hover {
 opacity: 0;
 content: none;
 background-color: #FFF;
 cursor: default;
}
 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 551px) and (max-width: 4000px) { /*styles for small screens in here*/

#navBar {
 width: 100%;
 float: none;
}

#navBar #navContent {
 width: 100%;
 float: none;
}

#navBar #navContent ul {
 display: block;
 height: 310px;
 width: 100%;
 float: none;
}

#navBar #navContent ul li {
 width: 100%;
 display: inline;
 height: 50px;
 float: none;
}

#navBar #navContent ul li a {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 float: none;
}

#navBar #navContent ul li a:hover {
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 float: none;
}

#navBar #navContent #menu {
 display: block;
 width: 40px;
 height: 30px;
 margin: 5px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 padding-top: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 float: right;
 border: 2px solid #AEC1D3;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #787878;
}

#navBar #navContent #menu:after {
 display: inline-block;
}

#navBar #navContent #server {
 position: absolute;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) { /*styles for tiny screens in here*/

html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
}

#navBar {
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 background-color: #454545;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 15px solid #2F2F2F;
 position: fixed;
}

#navBar #navContent {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 400px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: #454545;
}

#navBar #navContent ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 background-color: #454545;
 height: 100%;
}

#navBar #navContent ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
 display: block;
 background-color: #454545;
 width: 20%;
 width: calc(100% / 5);
}

#navBar #navContent ul li a {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: flex;
    /* flex-direction: column;*/
    align-items: center;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 24px;
 justify-content: center;
 color: #FFF;
 transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

#navBar #navContent ul li a:hover {
 background-color: #349BD4;
 color: #FFF;
 transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}

}
```

```html
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="slideFix" id="navBar">
    <div class="slideFix" id="navContent">
      <a href="#" id="menu"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <ul id="nav">
        <li>
          <a class="active">
            <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Store
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Forums
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Vote
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Users
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Contact
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div id="server" data-clipboard-text="play.climaxmc.org">
        play.climaxmc.org
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a id="pull">Menu</a>
  <ul class="test">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">How-to</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Web 2.0</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its basically because of the `transition` property applied through `CSS`. Right now I've disabled all the `transition` property for all the elements and it works as expected. Here is the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/32oumq5k/2/)**.

Above all, you have given `transition` property for all the things that happens on that particular `element`, which includes `hide` and `show` too. `transition:all .25s ease-in` etc and the `transition time` was so less which **0.25 seconds**. So you need to decide and make use of `CSS Transitions` properly and also make sure, when you have `transition-all` you don't perform any `jquery` animations. That will mis-behave as it happened now. With above `CSS transition` applied with property `all` you could just change `CSS` of element like `menu.css('display','block');` which takes care of animation the animations and yea do not forget to increase `transition time` to some `3s` or `4s`

Comment: So if i changed CSS animation from all to targeting specific things (mainly just color, background color and width) would it work? because i only know how to do fade animations in CSS and if i cant use both at the same time then its a big problem

Answer (score 0):

Based on Guruprasad Rao's answer, I fix style of `#navBar #navContent ul li a` by removing `height: 100%`

[ONLINE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/32oumq5k/5/)